Bitcoin Node starts initialblockchain download on every start
I setup a pruned bitcoin node with the following configuration
prune=550
dbcache=6192
par=4
maxconnections=20
server=1
rpcuser=testuser
rpcpassword=testpassword
datadir=/root/.bitcoin/blocks
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
walletnotify=/usr/bin/php8.1 -f /var/www/html/btcnotifyme.php %s

But i cannot get it to be consistent on node starts - every time i start the node itll start a initialdownload again and i have to wait 3-4 days for it to synchronize again and again - does anybody have an idea what could be the reason for this ?
I just start the node bitcoind -daemon and stop it with bitcoin-cli stop. Running the bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo also shows
"initialblockdownload": true and the blocks folder gets reset. I am using the 0.27.0 package.

Has been solved, you have to include -datadir in the startup command, somehow the datadir in bitcoin.conf does not work properly.
